# How to restart ble in arduino nRF52832

Tags: arduino, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, restart, nrf52

thank you for coming to see this question.

I am making a gas detector with nRF52832 module using Arduino.

I would like to change the bluetooth device name when gas is detected.
This is because if that happens, you can check the status of the gas detector in the Bluetooth device search stage.

I know there is no way to restart the nRF52832 module itself,
So I would like to know how to restart Bluetooth itself from the Bluefruit library.

Below is the code I applied. Thank you.

```
    #include <bluefruit.h>

// BLE Service
BLEDfu  bledfu;  // OTA DFU service
BLEDis  bledis;  // device information
BLEUart bleuart; // uart over ble
BLEBas  blebas;  // battery

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

#if CFG_DEBUG
  // Blocking wait for connection when debug mode is enabled via IDE
  while ( !Serial ) yield();
#endif

  bleStart(); //ble setup
}

void loop() {
  // Forward from BLEUART to HW Serial
  while ( bleuart.available() ) {
    uint8_t ch;
    ch = (uint8_t) bleuart.read();
    //    Serial.write(ch);
    if (ch == '0') {
      //change ble name [gas 0 detected]
    } else if (ch == '1') {
      s//change ble name [gas 1 detected]
    } else if (ch == '2') {
      //change ble name [gas 2 detected]
    }
  }
}

void bleStart() {
  //Ble set
  Bluefruit.autoConnLed(true);
  Bluefruit.configPrphBandwidth(BANDWIDTH_MAX);
  Bluefruit.begin();
  Bluefruit.setTxPower(4);    // Check bluefruit.h for supported values


  Bluefruit.setName(nameBuf); // change device name

 
 Bluefruit.Periph.setConnectCallback(connect_callback);
  Bluefruit.Periph.setDisconnectCallback(disconnect_callback);

  // To be consistent OTA DFU should be added first if it exists
  bledfu.begin();

  // Configure and Start Device Information Service
  bledis.setManufacturer("Adafruit Industries");
  bledis.setModel("Bluefruit Feather52");
  bledis.begin();

  // Configure and Start BLE Uart Service
  bleuart.begin();

  // Start BLE Battery Service
  blebas.begin();
  blebas.write(100);

  // Set up and start advertising
  startAdv();
}

void startAdv(void)
{
  // Advertising packet
  Bluefruit.Advertising.addFlags(BLE_GAP_ADV_FLAGS_LE_ONLY_GENERAL_DISC_MODE);
  Bluefruit.Advertising.addTxPower();

  // Include bleuart 128-bit uuid
  Bluefruit.Advertising.addService(bleuart);

  // Secondary Scan Response packet (optional)
  // Since there is no room for 'Name' in Advertising packet
  Bluefruit.ScanResponse.addName();

  /* Start Advertising
     - Enable auto advertising if disconnected
     - Interval:  fast mode = 20 ms, slow mode = 152.5 ms
     - Timeout for fast mode is 30 seconds
     - Start(timeout) with timeout = 0 will advertise forever (until connected)

     For recommended advertising interval
     https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1931/_index.html
  */
  Bluefruit.Advertising.restartOnDisconnect(true);
  Bluefruit.Advertising.setInterval(32, 244);    // in unit of 0.625 ms
  Bluefruit.Advertising.setFastTimeout(30);      // number of seconds in fast mode
  Bluefruit.Advertising.start(0);                // 0 = Don't stop advertising after n seconds
}
```

Comment: Changing the name during runtime might not be the best idea if you want to detect the device using a smartphone, They are using caching and your device name might not be updated

Answer (score 1):

Basically What you are looking for is changing the advertising name when gas is detected.

You can follow this procedure.

1. Detect the gas.
2. Stop the BLE advertisement.
   Bluefruit.Advertising.stop()
3. Change the BLE/GAP Device name
   void     setName            (const char* str);
4. Start the BLE advertisement again.
   Bluefruit.Advertising.start(0);